# CSC : warning SA1516: Elements should be separated by blank line -> Not showing the file

Tags: c#, .net

When it occurs in top-level programs, SA1516 does not emit the corresponding file:

[image]

Which file is called CSC?
I want to solve this SA1516 warning by adding a blank line where it is necessary. In other compilation warnings and errors, I just need to click on the error and it guides me and opens the corresponding file and line. This behavior does not happen in this case.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1516.md

Comment: Did you end up resolving this issue? I'm experiencing the same thing.

Comment: Solved by adding blank lines between different statements in Program.cs @JED

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solved by adding blank lines between different statements in **Program.cs**. See the following example:

[image: Example]

PS: based on Filip Kuthan answer.

Answer (score 9):

I've encountered this problem today aswell.

Explicitly adding namespace, class and Main method to Program class helped to solve this. What is tricky is the fact, that after all this you still need to restart VS for StyleCop to recognize the change, which made it quite hard to find the solution :-)

Code before:

```
using System.SomeNamespace;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
Something1();
var app = builder.Build();
Something2();
app.Run();
```

Code after:

```
using System.SomeNamespace;

namespace Name.Of.Namespace
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
            Something1();
            var app = builder.Build();
            Something2();
            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Dont forget to restart your VS and rebuild project.

Comment: Last straw! Seems like top-level statements aren't ready for prime time. Killing us with stuff like this in exchange for like 6 less lines of code is dumb. I'm removing top-level statements from all my projects.

Answer (score 3):

Top-level statements were [introduced in C# 9](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements).

`StyleCop 1.1` is the latest stable version of StyleCop and officially supports [up to C# 7.3](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers#c-language-versions).

`StyleCop 1.2` is still pre-release but supports `C# 8.0`. While not official `C# 9` support, it resolves the false-positive warning of this question. You may want to try upgrading to the [latest beta package](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/releases).

```
<PackageReference Include="StyleCop.Analyzers" Version="1.2.0-beta.435">
```

Restart Visual Studio after upgrading the package to clear the incorrect warning.

Comment: DO NOT USE A BETA of any package unless you have plenty of time to kill. There is no situation in the world that makes it worth the pain you'll eventually have when you become the first person to find an esoteric bug.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. When we used the react template to create a new ASP.Net Core SPA app on VS2022 and added StyleCop and Code Cracker and build the solution - we got this error on CSC .

Adding the namespace and Main to the program as mentioned, then restart the VS2022 and rebuild it - the error was fixed!

Comment: this is not  an answer, please remove it and add as a comment

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32728720)

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to StyleCop.Analyzers.Unstable and those errors are gone after that.